# When we assign a goal to a phase then how will the order of execution be executed?

Tags: java, maven

So lets say we have a random plugin and we bind some goal to a phase from the default lifecycle. Let's say we bind to the phase package which by default binds to the goal `jar:jar`. Now if we bind some goal to this phase when exactly will it be executed? Since we bind it to package I would expect it to run right after `jar:jar` however maven documentation specifies:

> If more than one goal is bound to a particular phase, the order used is that those from the packaging are executed first, followed by those configured in the POM.

Does this mean that the default goals bound to a phase are executed first before the goal that we manually bind to a phase or that the goal we bound to a phase will be executed at very last end (after deploy lifecycle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goals, specified in the POM, will be executed in the phases they are configured (or default if there is any for that goal), but **after** the goals which are bound by a [selected packaging](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#built-in-lifecycle-bindings).

So, if your POM specifies `<packaging>jar</packaging>`, and declares a plugin that explicitly binds to `package` phase, the plugin's goal will be executed **after** the default binding for `jar:jar`.

Answer (score 1):

The goal you specify in the POM will be executed in the specified phase in the lifecycle.